# Bs4 retornando apenas versão

Tags: python

Opa, estou criando uma ferramenta que procura a versão do wordpress e imprime na tela (requests + bs4).

Trecho do código:

```
def versao():
    r = requests.get('https://'+f'{site}')
    html = r.text

    sopinha = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    versao = sopinha.find_all('meta', attrs={'name':'generator'})
    print(versao)

versao()
```

Eu queria que ele retorna-se apenas o número da versão do wordpress, como por exemplo: 4.9.2

Porém ele retorna tudo isso: (Deixei em vermelho o que quero que retorne)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você buscou por todos os elementos `<meta>` da página. Não seria o caso de buscar apenas o que possui `name="generator"` e tratar seu valor?

Comment: Tentei tirar o meta porém dá o mesmo resultado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente utilizar `sopinha.find("meta", {"name":"generator"})`, isso deveria te retornar a linha completa caso queira reduzir ainda mais o retorno, tente: `sopinha.find("meta", {"name":"generator"})['content']`.